# Ionic 2 and Angularfire2 query

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm writing a query using Ionic 2 and Angularfire2 and I can't see the data result.

```
this.items = this.db.list('/usuarios', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'email',
        equalTo: user.email
    }
}).map( (response[])=>{
    return response;
});

console.log(this.items);
```

The return a FirebaseListObservable. How I get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must subscribe to an Observable:

```
this.items = this.db.list('/usuarios', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'email',
        equalTo: user.email
    }
}).map(items => items.map(item => item)).subscribe(items => console.log(items));
```